# How do i create 24hour Countdown time showing the status in a circular object

Tags: java

I want to create a time 24hour countdown when a button is click then the countdown begin. When the countdown is finish. It waiting for another click.. Am new to programming .please I need help

Comment: What did you try? What difficulties did you encounter when coding?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First you save the total time of seconds in a day inside a variable

```
int counterSeconds = 86400;
```

A nice formula to get the seconds format to h/m/s format is this one:

```
int hours = counterSeconds / 3600;
int minutes = (counterSeconds % 3600) / 60;
int seconds = counterSeconds % 60;
```

Then just make the interface using the swing library and with a loop update the values of the labels where you are going to add the numbers every second.